# layouting 2 divs with dynamic content

Tags: css

I need to layout 2 divs (http://jsfiddle.net/tWE8W/) positioned in a container with a fixed width and height:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="element"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <div class="element"></div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

- both divs contain divs of type *element* with fixed dimensions. the elements can be added and removed dynamically.
- div1 is positioned left. The elements should be stacked 2 high and grow to the right.
- div2 is positioned right.The elements should be positioned horizontally (float: left). When the elements reach the right corner of div2 (also the rght corner of the container). The should start a new line.
- div1 should have a dynamic width based on th enumber of elements it contains.

it only needs to work  on the latest version of Google Chrome.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yourself?

Comment: classic aproach with div float left, tables and flexlayout.

Comment: why the negative votes: it seems easy to do but after 5 days still havent got a working answer

Comment: that's because it is NOT easy to do.  unless you're ok with using JS...  are you?

Comment: I'm hoping I can solve this without js.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Flexible Box Layout](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/) for the boxes on the left like

```
A C E
B D
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/tWE8W/3/)**

### (Relevant) CSS

```
.left{
    float:left;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
}
```

[image]

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) is also quite good nowadays

**EDIT:**

You can fiddle with the align-content property to align the boxes on the left.

Setting `align-content: space-between;` spaces the boxes out like this:

[image]

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/tWE8W/15/)**

Comment: the left div has a big margin at the right. Is there a way to remove this margin? Also the margin seems to grow with the number of elements added

Comment: the elements should be aligned and spaced alike in both left and right div. The idea is that both divs  grow dynalmically with the number of elements

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understood right http://jsfiddle.net/nindos/8DTp2/9/

```
<style>
.container
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;

    border: 1px solid black;
}

.left,.right{float:left;width:50%;height:100%;overflow:auto}
.left{background-color:red}
.right{background-color:blue}
.element{display:inline-block;background-color:pink}</style>
```

Comment: thx, I did not mention that the left divs width should be based on the number of elements it contains.  It should grow/shrink when elements are added or removed. Also in you example they float left. They should stack like A C E first row B D second row